# Is it OK to use a first name as an initial and write in full in the biography of a paper

Tags: publications, personal-name

I would like to write my initial first name in the title of my paper and i.e with this format "Initial (for first name) Middlename Surname". Is it appropriate to write the full first name in the biography section of the paper i.e Full (First name) Middlename Surname? Note that I would like to keep this consistent.

Comment: It's not about "ethics", it's about allowing other people (and machines) to consistently identify you. If you present yourself with (even superficially) different names, people may (reasonably-enough) think that you are several different people, and so on. So, it's not ethics, it's practicalities. Especially over many different cultures, with many different traditions of names and such. There cannot be any sane "universal rule" (despite a general tendency to endorse north-western European name concepts), so think pragmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The question has been edited accordingly, but I hope to fully understand what are the things involved from experience. I mean, google scholar for example would capture the first initial and middle name as well as the surname. I would like to fully comprehend this issue better and it would hopefully benefit others in the future.

Comment: Your impulse is entirely reasonable... and/but even the concepts of "first name, middle name, surname" are not universal. The question is, for the moment, how to squeeze reality into that fake citation system. I do not know what will happen. Perhaps the ORCHID or other author databases will help, though, still, with several of these, if we don't know the "authoritative" version, there's still confusion. Facetiously: maybe just get your own Unicode character for your name. Emojis get them, why not people? :) (Good luck with all such stuff...)

Comment: Names don't go in titles of papers, and what do you mean the "biography section"?